# Candy Machine v2 and Phantom wallet: receive unknown

Tags: solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I deployed a Candy Machine v2 with sugar on mainnet and when I mint an NFT directly into a Phantom wallet the SPL token is unknown.

There is no documentation about this I can find.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely experiencing "bot tax".

Check the transaction which resulted in that unknown token and in the transaction log it should tell you why. E.g. because the candy machine is not live yet, you do not have enough SOL, or it is sold out already.

To fix it you will most likely have to update the candy machine configuration.

Comment: https://solscan.io/tx/2cyaEB2ZKKASr5CZofqgtcJ2SHGojeNdrxMMnMhYjxmU7tnvToVPeJyUwSw4w8p6bsz4EWUZ6T34jHVH3ERk2QHF    This is one of the transactions. I can't seem to find anything weird and Solcan lists the token name.